# PyMC: Vectorization or Fundamentally Different

Tags: python, probability, bayesian, pymc3, pymc

is there a fundamental difference between these pymc variable definitions:

```
r = pymc.Uniform(lower=-1, max=1, size=2)
step = [pymc.Slice(var=[r])]
```

and

```
r1 = pymc.Uniform(lower=-1, max=1)
r2 = pymc.Uniform(lower=-1, max=1)
step = [pymc.Slice(var=[r1]), pymc.Slice(var=[r2]) ]
```

?

I need to update a code using the slice algorithm and some 21 variables were defined taking the later approach. I am unsure if adopting the first definition might lead to significant differences in the posterior distributions.